# Can't access fetched data in useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm creating a random quotes generator but there's a problem. It just doesn't generate a random quote at the beginning. Please correct me so that the generate random quote works at least one time when rendering

```
    const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
    const [randomQuote, setRandomQuote] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => setQuotes(data))
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }

        fetchData();
        console.log('from useEffect', quotes);
        generateRandomQuote();
    }, []);

    console.log('After useEffect(): ', quotes);

    const generateRandomQuote = () => {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        const selectedQuote = quotes[randomIndex];
        setRandomQuote(selectedQuote);
    };
```

Comment: You dont wait for the async fetch to end. Try putting generateRandomQuote() in a then().

Comment: Or even better, go with `async` and `await` for all the asynchronous stuff. Mixing `.then()` and `async` is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: No matter if you await or not, it won't work because state is updated in the next render cycle

Comment: 1. Remove `.then(data => setQuotes(data))` 2.  `const data = fetchData();` 3.  `generateRandomQuote(data);` 4.  `const generateRandomQuote = (quotes) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete what Usman Ali Syed said, if the quotes array is not presented in the UI and  you just want the quotes array to be persistent between renderings, you can use **useRef** instead, here is the example:

```
const quotes = useRef([]);
const [randomQuote, setRandomQuote] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data =>quotes.current = data)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }

    fetchData();
    console.log('from useEffect', quotes);
    generateRandomQuote();
}, []);

console.log('After useEffect(): ', quotes);

const generateRandomQuote = () => {
    ...
    const selectedQuote = quotes.current[randomIndex];
    setRandomQuote(selectedQuote);
};
```

hope that helps a little bit!

Comment: The problem is that quotes array is an array of objects of quotes, like this: { quote: "Quote here", author: "Ali"}

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define the function fetchData inside the useEffect() that's kind of odd.
Secondly the fetchData seems to be an async function but you are not awaiting it.

```
await fetchData()
```

or

```
fetchData().then(()=>generateRandomQuote())
```

EDIT:
Konrad is right, you are attempting to use the state variable right after updating it but it won't work because a state update causes the component to re render.
Seems to me like you don't really need to have a "quotes" state variable. Inside of the fetchData function you can simply set the randomQuote variable which will be reflected on the frontend if you are displaying it there.
If you plan on doing something with the state variable after updating it you are going to have to put it in the useEffect dependency array.

Comment: I'm getting the quotes array but the random quote generator still doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work ? you mean the content of the quote is not displayed on the frontend ?

Comment: I get the quotes but not a random quote in the beginning, I only get it when I click a button

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `then` with `async/await`.
use either one but not both at once.

```
const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]); 
const [randomQuote, setRandomQuote] = useState(); 

useEffect(() => { 
   async()=>{ 
    await fetchData(); 
    console.log('from useEffect', quotes); 
    generateRandomQuote(); 
   } 
}, []);

async function fetchData() {
       const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
       const data = await res.json();
       setQuotes(data);
    } 

console.log('After useEffect(): ', quotes); 

const generateRandomQuote = () => { const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length); 
const selectedQuote = quotes[randomIndex]; setRandomQuote(selectedQuote); 
};
```